# "Process is not defined" during use Ajax with API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, dotenv

I have problem because I an error "*Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined*".
I want add my API_KEY to the folder .env but I can not do this. My code looks like: (this is **index.js**)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#textButton").click(function() {
    var APIkey = process.env.API_KEY; //here I want add my hiding API to variables API_KEY which is in folder .env
    const approvalText = $("#textCity").val();
    if (approvalText != '') {
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + approvalText + "&appid=" + APIkey + '&units=metric',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          $(".city_name").html(data.name + ', ' + data.sys.country);
        }
      });
    } else {
      alert("Please write city name on text field");
    }
  });
});
```

My structure of folders and subfolders

[image]

I have installed:
-node v12.18.4
-npm 6.14.6
and dotenv

How I can resolve my problem?

Comment: `process` is a `nodejs` thing - your code is browser code

Comment: You'd need a bundler like Webpack using something like the [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) to take values from your `.env` file and make it available to your runtime scripts

Comment: of course, then the issue is that the API Key will be plainly visible in the browser code - which of course it needs to be for browser code to use it - if you need a secret API key, then you'll need to make requests via your server rather than directly from the browser